# Give two different outputs in Thonny and Trinket. (python)

Tags: python, json

Following code was used in Thonny (offline) IDE and it works fine. But when I use the same code in trinket it gives me an error. What could be the reason?

```
def compare_prices(product_laughs,product_glomark):
    html_lau=requests.get(product_laughs).content 
    html_glo=requests.get(product_glomark).content #get the content of the site

    soup_lau=BeautifulSoup(html_lau,'html.parser')
    soup_glo=BeautifulSoup(html_glo,'html.parser')
    
    glo_products=soup_glo.find("script", type="application/ld+json")
    glomark_content=glo_products.text #glomark product list
    print(glomark_content)
    productList=json.loads(glomark_content)
```

This last statement gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/96aa9a060805dc3c/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    compare_prices(laughs_coconut,glomark_coconut)
  File "/tmp/sessions/96aa9a060805dc3c/compare_prices.py", line 27, in compare_prices
    productList=json.loads(glomark_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of Python in both?

Comment: You printed out `glomark_content` just before the line that caused the error - what was printed, that was different between the two environments?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: You printed out glomark_content just before the line that caused the error - what was printed, that was different between the two environments?                                                                    Thanks for the reply. Even that part is deleted, still I get the error.

Comment: The glomark_content is something like the following;